# Spring WebFlux Type Mismatch with Kotlin toMono()

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

I am getting the following compilation warning:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Any
Found: Customer?
```

when attempting to call the `toMono()` method on a nullable `Customer` instance:

```
@Service
class CustomerServiceImpl @Autowired constructor(
        val customers: ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Customer>
) : CustomerService {
    override fun getCustomer(id: Int): Mono<Customer?> {
        return customers[id].toMono()
    }
}
```

**CustomerService:**

```
interface CustomerService {
    fun getCustomer(id: Int): Mono<Customer?>
}
```

**AppConfig:**

```
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {
    companion object {
        val initialCustomers: Array<Customer> = arrayOf(
                Customer(1, "Jerry"),
                Customer(2, "James"),
                Customer(3, "John")
        )
    }

    @Bean
    fun createCustomers() = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Customer>(
            initialCustomers.associateBy(Customer::id)
    )
}
```

No such compilation warning exists when I define the return type in the `CustomerService` interface as a non-null `Customer` instance (`: Mono<Customer>`). What am I missing here? Any and all help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I should attach anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toMono()` extension which you seem to be using is defined like this:

```
fun <T : Any> T.toMono(): Mono<T> = Mono.just(this)
```

Since `T : Any`, the receiver must not be nullable.

I guess you'd need an extension like this:

```
fun <T : Any?> T.toMono(): Mono<T> = Mono.justOrEmpty(this)
```

*Disclaimer*: I haven't even tested whether this compiles.

Comment: Thank you! I did look at the source code here and saw that, though I've seen two blog posts and a book I'm reading contain examples of using `toMono()` with nullable objects. I will continue investigating

Comment: @MylesW I just learned from a watching a video that generic type parameters are assumed to be nullable by default, and if you don't want them to be nullable you have to make them extend `Any`.  So it looks like the method was explicitly created to be used on non-null objects.  But in my example extensionk, instead of `<T : Any?>` you can just write `<T>`, as nullability is assumed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Mono.justOrEmpty()` is what I was looking for here, fyi. This seems to solve the issue with nullable objects.